# The Method of Frobenius for $x^2y'' + x^2y' - \frac{3}{4}y = 0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is from Introduction to Ordinary Differential Equations, by Shepley Ross:

Use the method of Frobenius to find solutions near $x = 0$ of each of the differential equations in Exercises 5-32.

28. $x^2y'' + x^2y' - \frac{3}{4}y = 0.$

I've gone through a good portion of the steps but I'm not sure how to proceed. I found that when solving for $y$ corresponding to both roots $r_1 = \frac{3}{2}$ and $r_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$, you end up with essentially the same solution.

Letting $r = r_1 =  \frac{3}{2}$, we obtain

$$y = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} c_nx^{n + \frac{3}{2}} = c_0x^{\frac{3}{2}}\big(1 - \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{5}{32}x^2 - \frac{7}{192}x^3 + \dots \big).$$

Letting $r = r_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$, we obtain

$$y = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} c_nx^{n - \frac{1}{2}} = c_2x^{\frac{3}{2}}\big(1 - \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{5}{32}x^2 - \frac{7}{192}x^3 + \dots \big).$$

What I'm trying to find is a solution of the form

$$ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} c_n^{*}x^{n - \frac{1}{2}} + Cy_1(x) \ln x,$$

where $c_0^{*} \neq 0$ and $C \neq 0$. Using the method of reduction (letting $y = f(x)v$) is extremely tedious and just doesn't seem practical given this solution (Please note: I haven't gone over Bessel's Equation and Bessel Functions yet).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The recurrence relation with arbitrary $r$ gives
$$c_{r, k} = c_0 \prod_{1 \leq i \leq k} \left(
-\frac 1 {2 (2 i + 2 r - 3)} - \frac 3 {2 (2 i + 2 r + 1)} \right).$$
Then the ODE has solutions
$$y_1 = \sum_{k \geq 0} c_{3/2, k} x^{k + 3/2}, \\
y_2 = \lim_{r \to -1/2} \frac \partial {\partial r}
 (r + 1/2) \sum_{k \geq 0} c_{r, k} x^{k + r} = \\
\frac {y_1 \ln x} 8 +
 \frac {c_0} {\sqrt x} - \frac {c_0 \sqrt x} 2 - \frac {y_1} {16} +
 \frac 1 8 \sum_{k \geq 1} \sum_{1 \leq i \leq k} \left(
   \frac 2 {2 i + 1} - \frac 1 i - \frac 1 {i + 2} \right)
  c_{3/2, k} x^{k + 3/2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

First we check whether Frobenius's method can succeed.  The given equation reduces to
$$  y'' + y' − \frac{3}{4x^2} y = 0  \text{.}  $$
The coefficient of $y'$, $1$ has a pole of order less than or equal to $1$ at $x = 0$ (in fact it has no pole at $x = 0$, so has a pole of order $0$ there).  The coefficient of $y$ has a pole of order less than or equal to $2$ at $x = 0$.  So $x = 0$ is a regular singular point.

So we solve the indicial equation:
$$  \left. \left(r(r-1) + x^2 r - \frac{3}{4} \right)\right|_{x = 0} = 0  \text{,}  $$
giving $r_1 = 3/2$ and $r_2 = -1/2$.

Since the difference of these two roots is an integer, inserting a power series and solving the recurrence for the coefficients does not yield two linearly independent solutions, we only get one.  Use the larger root to get a solution $y_1$.

Since the two roots are separated by an integer (including zero, so if a root is repeated), a second solution is of the form
$$  y_2 = C y_1 \ln x + \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^{k+r_2}  \text{,}  $$
where $y_1$ is the solution you already found and the coefficients $C$ and the $b_k$ are to be determined.  (Once $b_0$ is chosen, typically by setting it to $1$, then $C$ and the $b_k$ up to but not including $b_{r_1 - r_2}$ are determined.  Then declare $b_{r_1 - r_2}$ arbitrarily, which forces values for all the remaining coefficients.)  (It is possible for $C = 0$ to happen.  I haven't checked whether this happens here.)